# How to make a button response on touch-screen mobile through html

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've had to create a website using standard HTML and CSS to be able to be used on website and mobile; the website works completely fine but mobile buttons don't seem to work! Is there any code that I should input in CSS/main to make reponsive..

This is my code for buttons:

```
<div id="Image">
<img src="image" alt="image" width="1200" height="557" usemap="imageMap"/>
<map name="imageMap">
<area id="STC" alt="imageALT" title="imageTitle" href="URL" shape="rect" coords="40,414,396,458"  target="_self"/>
<area id="PTE" alt="ImageALT" title="ImageTitle" href=" URL" shape="rect"    coords="41,483,397,527"  target="_self"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize image map coordinates you might find it easiest using a plugin, such as these.

http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps